# Gradle build failed with message: TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated **Android Studio** to **3.3** and now I can't build one of my  existing project, I have tried invalidate/restart, also checked `gradle-wrapper.properties`where gradle version is latest update:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }

dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.3"
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }

}


androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            ....
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'   
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '22.2.0'
    googleServicesVersion = '17.3.4'
    retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    [
            'cardview-v7', 'design'
    ].each {
        implementation "com.android.support:$it:$supportLibraryVersion"
    }

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"


    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk23:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$googleServicesVersion"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I'm trying to build project `preDebugBuild` error appears

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
```

and **Java compiler: (1 error)**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

If I run `assembleDebug`

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: 
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugKotlin.' 
...
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
```

Also if run `./gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.warning.mode=all`

```
The project name 'myapp-android production' contains at least one of the following characters:
[ , /, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |]. This has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. 
Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement
 (see https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[])
 for more details)

Could not resolve compiler classpath. 
Check if Kotlin Gradle plugin repository is configured in root project 'myapp-android production'
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseKotlin'.
```

How can I resolve this issue? This happened after Android Studio update.

**Update** result of `./gradlew --stacktrace assembleDebug`

```
    Could not resolve compiler classpath. Check if Kotlin Gradle plugin repository is configured in root project 'my_app_production'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugKotlin'.
> 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfo.getDependencies(LocalTaskInfo.java:89)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfo.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskInfo.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:168)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.addTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:126)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$CalculateTaskGraph.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:305)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.constructTaskGraph(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:190)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:145)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector.registerDependencies(DependencyInspector.java:118)
        at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector.afterResolve(DependencyInspector.java:173)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:370)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:352)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:340)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:327)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.afterResolve(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$5.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:542)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:524)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:509)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1800(DefaultConfiguration.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1037)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1025)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:444)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolve(DefaultConfiguration.java:434)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompileTool.getComputedCompilerClasspath$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$DefaultPropertyValue$1$1.create(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:83)
        at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:313)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$DefaultPropertyValue$1.get(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:80)
        at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$MemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$DefaultPropertyValue.getValue(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:138)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$DefaultPropertyValue.call(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:144)
        at org.gradle.util.GUtil.uncheckedCall(GUtil.java:459)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.add(BuildDependenciesOnlyFileCollectionResolveContext.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskPropertyFileCollection.visitContents(TaskPropertyFileCollection.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitDependencies(CompositeFileCollection.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:211)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:64)
        ... 90 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: That Exception is thrown when you try to access the second element of an array that has one or zero elements in it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506307/gradle-project-sync-failed-after-android-studio-3-1-update

Comment: @Stultuske This is an issue with Android Studio resolving dependencies, not a standard Index out of Bounds problem.

Comment: @jemo-mgebrishvili could you post the output of building with `--stacktrace`? On Android Studio Settings: Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Compiler -> Command-line Options. On the command line: `./gradlew --stacktrace assembleDebug`

Comment: Did you try using the same gradle config on a **New Project**?

Comment: Try degrading the gradle, there is some issue with new version. Also check if you have instant run enabled or not ?

Comment: What android gradle plugin are you using?Did you try disbling Instant run?

Comment: @LeonardoAcevedo please see update

Comment: have you enabled jetifier?

Comment: @KaranMer Enabled just now, but nothing were changed

Comment: did you enabled androidx also?

Comment: yes, android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Got same problem :((

Comment: I've had too many of these.  Always something like change compile to buld or something along those lines in the gradle files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downgrade the version of google service to 4.1.0 and the error will disappear. The problem seems to be in version 4.2.0.

**EDIT:**

Another alternative I found was to create a new empty project, copy the old project classes and import the dependencies into the gradle one by one. This problem occurs in projects that use google service version 4.2.0 and do not have two gradle files, one for the project and one for the module.

Comment: Thanks! I spent four days trying to fix this!

Answer (score 3):

Well, if this error started right after upgrading to Android Studio 3.3 then i recommend you should do the following steps...
But firstly make sure you backup your whole project.

- In Android Studio goto File > Project Structure and untick from "use embedded JDK" then click OK
- Goto Computer Settings (system settings) (win + pause key) then go to Advanced system settings>Environment variables. if JAVA_HOME not present then add it and set path to your installed JDK.
- As i couldn't find a direct approach to modify jdk path in my project that is upgraded in some way to android studio 3.3 settings, i did following(for the last step)
  BUT MAKE SURE YOU MAKE BACKUP BEFORE THIS.
  To make sure where i am guiding come to project view, I deleted ".grade", ".idea". Then rebuild the project and it should go fine now!!!

And as far as latest gradle it concerned it is 5.2.1 for that change it to
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip

And if you have doubt regarding kotlin plugin then see "Targeting Android" section in
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: Just for the BACKUP in all caps.

Comment: @Vanshaj-Daga, now build fails with message Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip'.

Comment: use distribution path with \ as  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip